# SQL sorting by two columns, ignore null

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table with two columns like so:

1. price (varchar)
2. discount (varchar)

These two hold the price and discount for all of the products in my database. When users view the products, I have multiple sorting modes available, one of which is `Sort by price: low to high`. In order to do this, I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT ... ORDER BY `discount` ASC, `price` ASC, `title` ASC");
```

This works fine for all rows where `discount` is defined, but in rows where `discount` is empty, they are sorted above the others, regardless of the value of `price`.

For example:

```
id|price|discount
-----------------
 1|20   |10
 2|25   |10
 3|15   |
 4|15   |
```

Will echo out in the order:

```
3, 4, 1, 2
```

---

How can I rewrite this statement to sort by `price` when `discount` has no value?

Comment: If the final price is `price - discount`, then shouldn't you `ORDER BY  price - discount ASC`?

Comment: agree with @PatrickQ, perhaps `ORDER BY price-ifnull(discount,0)` is more appropriate

Comment: @PatrickQ actually discount holds the new price of the item when the discount is applied, e.g. product 2 would be $10, not $15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` for this:

```
SELECT ... 
ORDER BY COALESCE(`discount`, `price`), `price`, `title`
```

This will first order by `discount` if it's not null, and then order by `price`.  For those items with the same discount, it will then order by the `price`, followed by the `title`.

Note: Depending on your desired results, you may want to remove the additional order by `price`.

Comment: Does my column in my table have to be `NULL` or `NOT NULL` for this to work?

Comment: @David -- for those records where discount exists, this will order by that amount, followed by the original price (which may not be needed), and then the title.  If the discount is null, this will sort by price then title.

Comment: Ah I see. I had to update those to be NULL instead of an empty string first. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

try with IFNULL? , i have created sample query on [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/552f5/4)

```
select * from product order by IFNULL(discount,price)
```